# How to make condition if booking is full

Tags: laravel

I made a web booking, I want a condition where every hour of the day for example at 09:30 is limited to 3 visitors, so when a visitor chooses a date, for example, the 2nd where the date is full, a message will appear that the clock is full, how about it ? Please help

controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        
            Pengunjung::create([
                'nik'=> $request->nik,
                'nama'=> $request->nama,
                'status'=> $request->status,
                'email'=> $request->email,
                'notelp'=> $request->notelp,
                'jenis'=> $request->jenis,
                'kec'=> $request->kec,
                'nop'=> $request->nop,
                'namaobjek'=> $request->namaobjek,
                'tanggal'=> $request->tanggal,
                'jam_id'=> $request->jam_id,
        
            ]);
        

        return redirect()->route('formsukses', $request);
    }
```

blade

```
<label>Tanggal Kunjungan</label>
                <input type="date" name="tanggal" class="form-control" required />

                <label>Jam Kunjungan</label>
                <select class="custom-select" name="jam_id" required>
                  <option selected>Pilih</option>
                  @foreach ($jams as $item)
                  <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->jam }}</option>
                  @endforeach
                </select>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to sync your store function with this:

```
$pengunjungs = Pengunjung::where('tanggal', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateString())->where('jam_id', $request->jam_id)->get();

if($pengunjungs->count() > 3){
    return response()->json('Mohon maaf. Kunjungan di jam '.$request->jam_id.' sudah penuh.');
}else{
    Pengunjung::create([...]);
    return...
}
```

Comment: Obligatory reminder that Stack overflow is an English-only site. This applies to comments as well; I've gone ahead and deleted the comments. If you'd like to continue, do so in English.

Comment: why are you still not able

Comment: can you give the example value of 'tanggal'?